# MacOS: What file does the command `last` get its information from?

Tags: files, find, osx, macintosh, last

Can't seem to find where this `last` command gets its information from. Does anyone know what file it uses (specifically for Unix macOS) ?

---

Tried `cat /var/log/wtmp`, `cat /var/run/utmp`, `cat /var/log/lastlog` but all I get is: `cat: [...]: No such file or directory` . Tried `cat /var/log/system.log` and `sudo cat /var/audit` but these aren't it either. Is it just me or ? Where is this file ?

Comment: What does `man last` say? On typical unix it is stored in `/var/log/wtmp` and on the FreeBSD I have handy it is `/var/log/utx.log`

Comment: Doesn't say anything about what file it uses.

Comment: `dtruss` is Mac's `strace` equivalent; you should be able to use `dtruss` to find this information.

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual (`man last` refers to `man utmpx`), `/var/run/utmpx`.

Comment: `man utmpx` only says this about the `utmpx` file. "`Currently logged in users are tracked in /var/run/utmpx`", whereas the `last` command displays the history of all login/outs since the file (that I'm looking for) was created. @DopeGhoti

Answer (score 1):

It used to be `/var/log/wtmp` before Mac OS 10.3, according to Apple header file commentary.  That file no longer exists and is not used.  The underlying C library functions for accessing the login database, upon which `last` is based, now talk to ASL.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). *[The Unix login database](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/unix-login-database.html)*. Frequently Given Answers.